# How to Cygwin Xwin -query an Ubuntu 11.10 Xserver?

Tags: ubuntu, cygwin, x-server

I am running **Cygwin 1.7** on **Win7 Pro x64**, and I can query my **Ubuntu 10.04 LTS** server just fine.

```
XWin.exe -clipboard -once -rootless -nodecoration -notrayicon -query $IP_ADDRESS
```

I recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 with XFCE desktop on another machine, and I cannot connect to this one.

Of course, I enabled TCP and XDMCP in LightDM using **/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf**

```
[SeatDefaults]
# ...
xserver-allow-tcp=true

[XDMCPServer]
enabled=true
```

and I think the fact that I can connect using my **Xubuntu 11.10** laptop proves that it works.

```
X -query $IP_ADDRESS :1
```

**Xwin** fails to connect, while logging something like:

```
[333305.324] XDMCP fatal error: Session failed Failed to connect to display :0
[333305.324] 
[333305.324] Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Today I updated Cygwin.

```
CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 1.7.9(0.237/5/3) 2011-03-29 10:10
```

Still doesn't work. Does anyone have a clue as to what 'feature' the new and improved LightDM or Xserver has that I forgot to take into account?

Oh and did I mention the exact same **Cygwin/Xwin** connects to **Ubuntu 10.04** just fine, using the same command line (different IP of course)?

Comment: Gilles, you have edited out all references to Xubuntu. However, Xubuntu-desktop uses a whole different set of libraries and tools, not to forget that Unity (Ubuntu) is not made for remote desktopping to begin with. Both of which could be relevant in some way, imo. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what the guys over at *Cygwin/X* are doing to make this fail. And I don't know why I cannot find any help or even mention of similar trouble anywhere in this galaxy that is within the reach of Google. I believe I am not the only one using the software, so the lack of help puzzles me.

But let me provide a solution to my own question; I discovered that **VCXsrv.exe** is some kind of *Cygwin/X* clone in a way.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/

> VcXsrv Windows X-server based on the xorg git sources (like xming or
>   cygwin's xwin), but compiled with Visual C++ 2010.

It works almost the same, except you need to add the **-from [ip-address]** command line option. No idea why. But it works:

```
vcxsrv.exe -clipboard -once -rootless -nodecoration -notrayicon -query [target hostname or ip] -from [current (local) ip]
```

Tested with both Xubuntu and xubuntu-desktop on Ubuntu. (XFCE)

Comment: The `-from` option is available even with cygwin's `Xwin`.  

I was recently trying to query to OpenBSD `xdm` with cygwin's Xwin, and noticed that in the remote side's /var/log/xdm.log, in time with the connection attempts, it was outputting `Starting X server on 10.1.8.14:0` which suggests Xwin was transmitting the wrong address as I am not using any 10.x subnet on the Windows box.  Explicitly passing the ip with `-from` made it work.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I just added `-from your.ip.v4.addr` to the config line of XWin.exe, and it's now working for me. Both my windows 7 and the linux host were doing IPv6. I think that Xwin/LightDM don't know how to handle the IPv4/IPv6 mix.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and adding `-from` fixed it.

```
/usr/bin/XWin -query kvant -nodecoration -lesspointer -from 192.168.1.132
```

where "kvant" is the remote host and 192.168.1.132 is the client running the Xserver.

However, after upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04 on the server, this is PITIFULLY slow. 
9.x that I used to have was actually quite useful & snappy.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue which was resolved by adding the "from" option. This is my windows .bat file content (could help someone else):

```
@echo on

C:
chdir C:\cygwin\bin
bash --login -i -c '/bin/XWin -query server_ip -from client_ip'
pause
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Unix & Linux! I formatted your answer to make it easier to read, and taken away wording that is assumed for an answer. If you have an answer that is very similar to another's, simply upvote their answer and/or add a comment to theirs.

Comment: Saying "thanks for this" makes this post look like *not an answer* (and liable to be deleted as such) - see [answer]. Jeff helpfully edited it to make it look more like an answer by removing the extraneous text that would not be helpful to others with the same problem. Somehow, years later, this post has appeared in the Low Quality Posts review queue so I've now re-edited it (instead of voting to delete).